# ¿Por qué tengo que agregar el pseudo-elemento :after cuando uso animaciones de texto en CSS?

Tags: css

Estoy aprendiendo animaciones en CSS, no he tenido problemas con propiedades como **letter-spacing** dentro de los @keyframes.

Mi problema surge cuando quiero hacer una animación que cambie el contenido de un elemento y lo regrese a como era. Usando la propiedad **content**

Buscando por internet me encuentro con que tengo que usar el pseudo-elemento **:after** justo después de mi elemento (en este caso div container) seleccionado.

```css
.container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    /* border: 1px solid black; */
    height: 900px;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
   
    flex-direction: column;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

*{
    font-family: 'Bakbak One', cursive;
}

.hola_mundo {
    letter-spacing: -10px;
    animation-name: introduccion;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

h1{
    border: 1px solid white;
}

body{
    background: linear-gradient(RGB(35,38,46), RGB(48,74,107));
}

@keyframes introduccion {
    0%{
        letter-spacing: -10px;
    }

    50%{
        letter-spacing: 5px;
    }

    100% {
        letter-spacing: -10px;
    }
}

.mi_nombre:after{
    content: 'Alexis Zárate';
    font-size: 30px;
    animation-name: nombre;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation
}

@keyframes nombre {
    0%{
        content: 'Alexis Zárate';
    }

    50%{
        content: 'Ingeniero';
    }

    100%{
        content: 'Alexis Zárate';
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bakbak+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles2.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="hola_mundo">
            <h1>HOLA MUNDO</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="mi_nombre">
            <!-- Alexis Zárate -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

El código funciona correctamente. Pero no sé por qué funciona cuando agrego :after como pseudo-elemento.

**Gracias de antemano**

Comment: `:after` se utiliza para añadir contenido después del elemento que seleccionas, es decir, en tu caso se utiliza `:after` para agregar contenido ("Alexis Zárate") después del elemento de la clase `mi_nombre` y luego animar ese contenido (que es lo que ocurre en tu ejemplo).

Comment: Gracias por comentar. Me quedó una duda, por qué existe la necesidad de agregar ese pseudoelemento? Por qué no me permite animar el contenido dentro del elemento?